# Ldap3 python modify password

Tags: python, change-password, ldap3

Have some problem with modify password in AD using modifyResponse.
On ipa.demo1.freeipa.org script is working. On my win 2012 server i have success response, but password not changing.

Code

```
    server = ldap3.Server('ipa.demo1.freeipa.org')
    conn = ldap3.Connection(server, 'uid=admin', 'pwd', auto_bind=True)
    conn.modify(
      'uid=user_name',{
          'userPassword' : [(ldap3.MODIFY_REPLACE, ['newpasswd'] )]
      }
    )
```

Connect

```
ldap://ipa.demo1.freeipa.org:389 - cleartext - user: uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org - not lazy - bound       - open - <local: 172.28.0.12:46261 - remote: 52.57.162.88:389> - tls not started - listening - SyncStrategy - internal decoder
```

Response

```
{'result': 0, 'description': 'success', 'dn': '', 'message': '', 'referrals': None, 'type': 'modifyResponse'}
```

And pwd is changing.

On my server i have same connect and response. But pwd has not changed.
So... Whats my problem?)